# Some js/css loading as 200 instead of 304 on some of my pages

Tags: javascript, css

I have two PHP pages. On both I am referring to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

just before the close of body tag.

Problem is that while I am analyzing them via the Chrome network tab, I see that both these resources are loading with 200 code on one php, while as 304 on other PHP. This means that on the page where they are loading as 200, they do not get loaded from cache.

[image]

[image]

Both page seem similar to me, so I am not sure what might be causing this difference.
Any pointers please?

Comment: Somtimes it's an error of chrome. And closing all tabs and restarting chrome solves strange behaviour of the cache. Beside that, are you sure caching is enabled while the console is open?

Comment: The "Disable Cache" checkbox is unchecked in both pages. i will try reopening Chrome

Comment: bah! reopening Chrome brought all requests to 304! What time waste :( Thanks t.niese!. I hope somebody is tracking this as an issue in Chrome? This might be causing unintended traffic on so many pages? You may post your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: To me it seems to just be a problem while the DevTools are opened, closing them also made the cache work correctly for me, but if you reopen the DevTools without a restart of chrome the behavior is wrong again. I also once searched for the problem and I think there is a issue for it, but i can't find anything right now.

Comment: perhaps this is the issue? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44867

Comment: this is expected behavior, the first request is obtained from the server, the second from chache. whats wrong?

Comment: @Deuterium, the problem, which is resolved now, was that two exact same page workflow, but js loading always as 200 on one page, and as 304 always on other page. It was Chrome issue, fixed by restarting the browser.